# sinon stub calls fake calling actual function

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, stubbing, sinon-chai

I'm having situation where I want to write unit test cases for a function to make sure if it is working fine or not. So I have created stub for that specific function and when I tries to calls fake that stub, the function is actually getting called instead of fake call. Below is my scenario:

- I have an main function from where I'm calling the function saveData(**).
- saveData(**) function is calling AWS SQS to save an message to DB

Below is my main function:

```
'use strict';
async function mainFunction() {
  try {
    await saveData(
      name,
      age,
    );
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error - [%s]', e);
    return null;
  }
}    
module.exports = { mainFunction };
```

Below is my saveData(**) function:

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sqs = new AWS.SQS();
const saveData = async (
  name,
  age,
) => {
    await sendMessage(JSON.stringify(dbData));
    const params = {
        DelaySeconds: <some_delay>,
        MessageAttributes: <messageAttributes>,
        MessageBody: {name:name, age:age},
        QueueUrl: <URL_FOR_QUEUE>,
      };
      return sqs.sendMessage(params).promise();
  return true;
};
module.exports = {
  saveData,
};
```

And my test case is,

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('app-module-path').addPath('./src');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const app = express();
const sqsSender = require('lib/queue');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const main = require('../../../src/main-function');
const routes = require('routes');
routes.configure(app);
let mainFunctionStub;
let saveDataStub;

describe('/v1/main', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mainFunctionStub = sinon.stub(main, 'mainFunction');
    saveDataStub = sinon.stub(sqsSender, 'saveData');
  });
  describe('Test', () => {
    it(`should return success`, (done) => {
      const name = 'Name';
      const age = 'Age';
      saveDataStub.resolves({
        name,
        age,
      });
    });
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    mainFunctionStub.restore();
    mainFunctionStub.reset();

    saveDataStub.restore();
    saveDataStub.reset();
  });
});
```

But this test is returning,

```
error: Jun-20-2021 20:07:05:    Error - [Error [ConfigError]: Missing region in config
```

and,

```
Error: Timeout of 3500ms exceeded.
```

From this error I can say that this is actually calling SQS function instead of faking. How can I resolve this or how can I fake call to this function? I'm new to this unit testing so any help would be appriciated.

Comment: What do you want to test? `mainFunction` or `saveData`?

Comment: I want to test both function combined. For ex. I want to check if saveData is getting called or not from mainFunction

Answer (score 1):

Stubbing works by replacing the property on the exports object. Since the `require` happens before sinon replaces the function, you capture the reference to the original function instead of dynamically using the currently set one.

You haven't showed your `require` calls in the main file, but from the call-site I infer you're importing it like `const { saveData } = require('../foo/sqsSender')`. This means you're grabbing the function off of the object when first loading the code. If you instead keep a reference to the `sqsSender` *module* instead, and reference the function on invocation, the stub should work.

```
'use strict';
// Don't destructure / grab the function.
const sqsSender = require("../foo/sqsSender")+

async function mainFunction() {
  try {
    // Use reference through module
    await sqsSender.saveData(
      name,
      age,
    );
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error - [%s]', e);
    return null;
  }
}

module.exports = { mainFunction };
```